# What is the best way extract JSON data from an api url using javascript and a GET request?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, eclipse, get

I've hit a wall trying to figure out how to send a request to the [BandsInTown API](https://www.bandsintown.com/api/requests#artists-events) and be able to extract a few elements (datetime and venue latitude and longitude) from the returned JSON page that contains music event information. I'm pretty new to JavaScript and web development so any help is much appreciated! The URL I'm using as a request is: http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/Hippo%20Campus/events.json?lapi_version=2.0&app_id=music_matcher

where I will implement flexibility to change the artist called.

I'm not sure if I should add the 'callback=*something*' param in the url or not also. I've looked into the 'requests' library through Node.js but I'm not totally sure how to get Node.js and npm to work through Eclipse Neon (the IDE I'm using) so I was really trying to just keep it straightforward and find a pure javascript solution that I could implement directly into my script in Eclipse. I just don't quite understand how to extract the JSON and call it later in my script as `results[0].venue.latitude` (in order to return latitude of venue) or whatever the 'results' object would be called (this is also part of my issue). Do I even need to put this information into an object?

Comment: So you are waiting to be able to parse the returned data, treat it as a JSON object and not a big string?

Comment: Yes I think so. Whatever will allow me to access the specific values within the api url JSON document. I'm not sure how to import it and save the individual values.

Comment: Importing and saving the individual values will depend on how your code is laid out and when you want to access the returned data but JSON.parse() may help you.

Comment: Thank you Sane, I used your advice in addition to this [other page](https://github.com/learnTrack/Q-A/issues/8) (I added `var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);`) and it works great!

Comment: One of you should post an answer and accept it.  Also @crispEtomE next time you ask a question, show the code you're already using so we can provide an answer in context.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using JSON.parse() in addition to an async HTTP request like this:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) { //theURL or a path to file
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        if (callback) {
            callback(data);
        }                   
    }
};

httpRequest.open('GET', theUrl, true); 
httpRequest.send(null);
}
```

and calling it:

```
httpGetAsync(url, function(data) {
document.write(data[0].venue.latitude);
document.write(data[0].venue.longitude);
document.write(data[0].datetime);
});
```

However, this method only allows me to make one clean call to the api. When I try to make multiple calls using a loop that calls the function with different urls, my script seems to terminate after the first one. So this is still an issue for my application of this.